# VB.NET HiT ODBC/400 Connection String properties not showing

Tags: vb.net, odbc, ibm-midrange

This is the connection string that I am using:

```
 CxnStr = String.Format("Driver=HiT ODBC/400 Optimized 32bit; UID='{0}'; DPC=0; SSL=0; ChCtg=0; CchUI=0; UnqTb=0; HoldC=1; RmBlk=1; BlkSz=512;BufSz=32767;Rows=0; Libs=0;CSID=0;Stats=1; SpCl=0;Hgls=1; TmOut=9999; NtNm=APPN;MdNm=QSERVER;CmtLvl=0;RdOy=1;SDK=0;Lang=;Pkg=1,1,; CdPg=037; IPAdr='{1}'; APPCRtr=10; Server='{2}'; Database='{3}'; PWD='{4}'", "L10646", HostName, HostName, BasisDatabase, PW)
```

I am creating a connection using this code:

```
 Try
            Using Con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(CxnStr)
                Using Command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(SQL, Con)
                    Command.CommandTimeout = 0
                    Con.ConnectionTimeout = 0
                    Con.Open()

                    Using BasDA As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(Command)
                        BasDA.Fill(DT)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

When the connection goes to open, it throws an exception saying:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

When I look at my Con variable, many of the parameters that I am assigning are not populated, like Database, Data source, etc.

I have the correct ODBC driver installed, as verified by the ODBCad32.exe program located in C:\Windows\SYSWOW6. The drivers tab shows that the HiT ODBC driver is installed.

What am I doing wrong? I have the driver installed, but even if I didn't the connection string is not filling in the connection properties properly!

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dillon,
Did you get an answer?  I just wrote my first .net accessing db2 and this does not look like a good connection string.

This redbook is a little older. But you should find some good information on setting up your connection string.
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html

You can use ADO instead of ODBC.

Comment: Thanks! I NEED to use ODBC though, it is a workplace restriction set (seems silly, trust me on that one) by our internal IT department and management. Turns out this connection string was fine, it was an access issue where my PC, being behind a certain corporate firewall, was not allowed access to the server. I was able to get access and magically it worked, despite what the error implied the actual issue was.